# NodeJS Set() with string is producing unreasonably large memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, ecmascript-6, set

I found that using ES6 new Set() on NodeJS will increase in memory consumption for string inputs, even when values are repeated. Please see the below example, writing 1 to 1e6 to a Set in integer and string.

The integer version will keep ~60MB of RSS usage. Where as the same numbers in string will result in increasing consumption of the RAM, at the end of the script it uses up almost 1GB of RAM. Any ideas?

```js
'use strict';

// Integer
let setA = new Set();
for(let i=0; i<=3e7; i++){
 
 setA.add(i%1e6);
 
 if(i%1e6 == 0){
  console.log("Now: ", i)
  let m = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log('RSS ' + Math.round(m['rss']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, heapTotal ' + Math.round(m['heapTotal']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, heapUsed ' + Math.round(m['heapUsed']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, external ' + Math.round(m['external']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB\n');
 }
}
setA = {};

// String
let setB = new Set();
for(let i=0; i<=3e7; i++){
 
 setB.add((i%1e6) + '');
 
 if(i%1e6 == 0){
  console.log("Now: ", i)
  let m = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log('RSS ' + Math.round(m['rss']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, heapTotal ' + Math.round(m['heapTotal']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, heapUsed ' + Math.round(m['heapUsed']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB, external ' + Math.round(m['external']/1024/10.24)/100 + 
   ' MB\n');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this with Node v6, but can't with Node v8, so I guess there was an implementation (or perhaps GC?) issue that got solved in between those two versions.

Final result for v8:

```
Now:  30000000
RSS 99.11 MB, heapTotal 85.5 MB, heapUsed 79.16 MB, external 0.01 MB
```

(although the *max* RSS is around 350MB, so the difference, I assume, is because of garbage collection)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This doesn't happen again after I updated to v8.0.